# Create a Pop-up with Address Bar

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm trying to have a pop-up feature that carries the address bar.

Sample:

Click on one the footer's link:

https://publicesmapplicant.ontariocolleges.ca/uniquesig412e2072afb0216a1e01313b11cd0c31/uniquesig0/en/help/Details/4

Note: i will have to kind of pop-ups, one will have youtube video and the other will have some content.

Thanks

Comment: Internet has a lot of examples: http://www.google.it/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=javascript+pop+windows

Comment: Ok, good. I was trying to find the right resources.

Comment: hey, you know if your ever wondering how some thing is done on a web page you can always view the source, or use browser addons such as firebug, newer versions of chrome hot keys `Ctrl + Shift + J`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should answer your doubts under the specs > location parameter:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

also, you could use a link that has an attribute of `target=_blank` but i think this ones deprecated. haven't used this method ever since

Answer (score 0):

Experiment with `window.open`:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp. For your case, check the `location` option.